# PHP parse multiple values from foreach loop to other php file

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to get multiple values out a foreach loop from file one.php to file two.php. I'm trying to parse them with:

from file one.php:

```
var_dump($key) //this gives string(19) "key1" string(19) "key2" string(19) "key3"
       session_start(); 
       $_SESSION['thekeys'] = $key;
```

to two.php

```
session_start(); 
echo $_SESSION['thekeys'];
```

However the echo in file two.php gives only the last key ("key3"). How would I parse all the values to two.php? Should I make it in an array or some?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your full code, not parts of it.

Comment: How can `var_dump($key)` give multiple values?

Comment: @h2ooooooo: It can (when you do it multiple times) -- I think the OP is doing the `var_dump()` inside a `foreach` loop.

Comment: It's an explode from an foreach loop.

Comment: @AmalMurali That'd make a lot more sense - then it also totally makes sense that `$key` is always the last one if he overrides it in a for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a `foreach` and then send the new array to the `$_SESSION` array:

**one.php**

```
$_SESSION['arrayOfKeys'][] = $tempArray;
```

**two.php:**

```
print_r($_SESSION['arrayOfKeys']);
```

It should work.

Comment: You've accidentally mixed `(` and `)` with its correct `[` and `]` characters (when accessing arrays).

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your keys in every foreach loop.

Just use an array to pass it.
This could be helpful:
http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions/7

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following foreach loop:

```
foreach($keys as $key)
{


}
```

Then try this snippet:

```
$keys_array
foreach($keys as $key)
{
   $keys_array[] = $key;
}
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['thekeys'] = $keys_array;
//var_dump($_SESSION['thekeys'] => key1, key2, key3
```